# MYSQL delete records that are duplicated more than 'x'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

im trying to clean up my WP login log and delete records where more than 500 login attempts were done from the same ip. i got this:

```
DELETE
FROM wp_simple_login_log
HAVING COUNT(ip) > 500
```

but sql says smth is wrong with this statement

Comment: having is work with group by;

Comment: You can use WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM wp_simple_login_log 
WHERE ip IN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
       SELECT ip
       FROM wp_simple_login_log
       HAVING COUNT(ip) > 500
   ) tmp
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like this:

```
DELETE wpl
FROM wp_simple_login_log wpl
INNER JOIN    
(
    SELECT ip,count(ip) FROM wp_simple_login_log wpl_sub 
    GROUP BY ip 
    HAVING COUNT(ip) > 500 
) sub
ON wpl.ip = sub.ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_simple_login_log WHERE ip IN 
  (SELECT ip FROM
        (SELECT ip,count(*) as nr FROM wp_simple_login GROUP BY ip) x
  WHERE nr > 500)
```

I am not sure if there is an even shorter or more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: 
Change your table ordertable and id is column name

```
 DELETE FROM ordertable where id IN ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM
 ordertable group by id having count(id)>1) AS X) ;
```